# Первое использование Sass (через приложение)

Tags: sass, препроцессор

Нужно ли скачивать на Windows Sass, если использовать одно из множества приложений под Windows, например Prepros? Т.е нужно ли ставить Ruby или все и так будет работать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретно в случае с Prepros: по-умолчанию Sass компилируется в нем с помощью [Libsass](http://github.com/sass/libsass) - реализации Sass на C/C++. И библиотеки Libsass устанавливаются вместе с Prepros, поэтому для поддержки Sass в Prepros, отдельно устанавливать Ruby и Sass - не нужно.

P.S. Вероятно некий минимальный пакет Ruby в Prepros тоже есть, потому что компиляция Slim поддерживается тоже "из коробки", а Slim работает на Ruby. Так что - в случае с Prepros - на windows можно не ставить ни Ruby, ни Sass, все будет работать в рамках Prepros.

Comment: Поправка: libsass - это C/C++ implementation of a Sass compiler.
https://github.com/sass/libsass
На Ноде написан же node-sass.

Comment: Благодарю за замечание, обновил ответ.

Comment: `node-sass` использует под капотом `libsass`, так что это не такое уж большое заблуждение :)

Comment: @D-side Node-sass is a library that provides binding for Node.js to LibSass. Точняк.